# Unable to get customized result using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to figure out how I can modify my existing regex pattern or create a new one to get all the lines that contain `dear` in them. If matched then, the script should print all those lines from `:` to the end of those lines. String manipulation is not an option here to scoop out the result.

I tried with:

```
import re

instr = """
Expression: It's been a while man.
Expression: How have you been moron?
Expression: Good to see you dear.
Greeting: How is everything dear?
Greeting: Hi dear, how are you?
"""
pattern = r'.*(?<=dear)'

for item in instr.splitlines():
    if re.search(pattern, item):
        print(item)
```

The result I'm getting:

```
Expression: Good to see you dear.
Greeting: How is everything dear?
Greeting: Hi dear, how are you?
```

What I wish to get:

```
Good to see you dear.
How is everything dear?
Hi dear, how are you?
```

***How can I get the customized result using regex?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a positive Lookbehind to only capture what comes after the colon. Something like this should work:

```
(?<=:).*\bdear\b.*
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CnBQS7/1)**.

I used the word boundary assertion `\b` to avoid matching things like "deaerator". Feel free to remove them if that's not the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be using an anchor `^` and a capturing group:

```
^[^:]*:\s*(.*\bdear\b.*)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[^:]*`:`Match 0+ times not`:`, then`:`
- `\s*` Match 0+ times a whitespace char
- `(` Capturing group

  - `.*\bdear\b.*` Match dear between wordboundaries and any char left and right of it
- `)` Close capturing group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dsx2Sj/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/dCCjmh)

For example:

```
import re

instr = """
Expression: It's been a while man.
Expression: How have you been moron?
Expression: Good to see you dear.
Greeting: How is everything dear?
Greeting: Hi dear, how are you?
"""
pattern = r'^[^:]*:\s*(.*\bdear\b.*)'

for item in instr.splitlines():
    res = re.search(pattern, item)
    if res:
        print(res.group(1))
```

Result

```
Good to see you dear.
How is everything dear?
Hi dear, how are you?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> for m in re.finditer(r'^[^:]+:\s*(.*dear.*)', instr, flags=re.M):
...     print(m[1])
... 
Good to see you dear.
How is everything dear?
Hi dear, how are you?
```

- `re.finditer` to iterate over all the matches
- `flags=re.M` so that `^` and `$` anchors will match per line, instead of once per whole string
- `^[^:]+:\s*` to cover string from start of line up to `:` and optional whitespaces
- `(.*dear.*)` match rest of the line if it contains `dear` (note that `.` will not match newline characters by default)
- As the required string is inside capture group, `m[1]` will give only that portion instead of whole line

  - use `m.group(1)` if Python version is less than 3.6

Answer (score 1):

This expression,

```
(?=:.*\bdear\b):\s*(.*)
```

might work here.

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/zpdDhs/1/), if you wish to explore further or modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/zpdDhs/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

#### Test with `re.findall`

```
import re

regex = r"(?=:.*\bdear\b):\s*(.*)"

test_str = ("Expression: It's been a while man.\n"
    "Expression: How have you been moron?\n"
    "Expression: Good to see you dear.\n"
    "Greeting:      How is everything dear?\n"
    "Greeting: Hi dear, how are you?\n"
    "Greeting:   Hi dear, how are you?\n"
    "dear: Hi there, how are you?")

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

#### Test with `re.finditer`

```
import re

regex = r"(?=:.*\bdear\b):\s*(.*)"

test_str = ("Expression: It's been a while man.\n"
    "Expression: How have you been moron?\n"
    "Expression: Good to see you dear.\n"
    "Greeting:      How is everything dear?\n"
    "Greeting: Hi dear, how are you?\n"
    "Greeting:   Hi dear, how are you?\n"
    "dear: Hi there, how are you?")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```